# PHP file size is unchanged after appending

Tags: php, caching, file-io, filesize

I am facing a problem with PHP file I/O.

```
$file = fopen("/tmp/test.txt", "w");
fwrite($file,"hi there\n");
fclose($file);
echo filesize("/tmp/test.txt")."\n"; # displays 9

$file = fopen("/tmp/test.txt", "a");
fwrite($file,"hi there\n");
fclose($file);
echo filesize("/tmp/test.txt")."\n"; # also displays 9 !!!!!!!
```

As one can see, I am changing the file size after the initial write by appending to it. Why do I get 9 as file size in both the cases? I'm expecting 18 as the output in case 2.

Comment: What is the file's content after execution of this script ?

Comment: Dear hsz it has expected contents. It has 18 characters.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to clear file status cache by calling the function [clearstatcache](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) **before** you call the `filesize()` again after modifying the file:

```
// write into file.
// call filesize()

clearstatcache();

// append to the fiile.
// call filesize()
```

In order to get better performance PHP caches the result of `filesize()` so you need to tell PHP to clear that cache before you call the `filesize()` again on a modified file.